# Can I release an object created outside a block that uses it before the block is run?

Tags: objective-c, memory-management, objective-c-blocks

Can `myArray` be safely released before the block?

```
NSMutableArray *myArray = [[NSMutableArray alloc] init];
[myArray addObject:@"a"];
[myArray addObject:@"b"];

// releasing here causes an invalid object to be used inside the block?
[myArray release];

CCCallBlock *block = [CCCallBlock actionWithBlock:^{
    // print myArray contents to console
}];

[myNode runAction:block];
```

Answer (score 4, accepted):

No, you cannot release the array before the block, because the objects inside the array and the array itself will not be usable after the call of release, before your block gets a chance to retain it.

You can make your array autoreleased, in which case the release would happen after the function exits.

```
NSMutableArray *myArray = [NSMutableArray array];
[myArray addObject:@"a"];
[myArray addObject:@"b"];

CCCallBlock *block = [CCCallBlock actionWithBlock:^{
    // print myArray contents to console
}];

[myNode runAction:block];
```

Comment: @Richard: ...which happens after the method exits.

Comment: @JoshCaswell yes, but it's not guaranteed to be a valid pointer when the block is called, no?

Comment: @RichardJ.RossIII The block would retain the array when it is created, not when it is called.

Comment: You don't have to use `autorelease`. You could simply move the `release` until after the invocation of `-runAction:`. Either `-runAction:` is synchronous, so the block won't be used after it returns or it is asynchronous in which case it has to copy the block before returning and the block will retain `myArray` when it is copied.

Answer (score 4):

To add to what the other people said, without `autorelease`, you can release the array after the block is created, if you no longer use the array after that.

```
NSMutableArray *myArray = [[NSMutableArray alloc] init];
[myArray addObject:@"a"];
[myArray addObject:@"b"];

CCCallBlock *block = [CCCallBlock actionWithBlock:^{
    // print myArray contents to console
}];
[myArray release];

[myNode runAction:block];
```

The block retains the captured objects (the array) when it is created.

Answer (score 2):

No. You would retain a dangling pointer in the block.